# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass:: with null json value

Tags: php, json, stdclass

my test.json files :

```
{
  "data1": "test1",
  "data2": "test2",
  "data3": "test3",
  "data4": "test4",
  "data5": "test5",
  "data6": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    "key5": "value5",
    "key6": "value6",
    "key7": "value7"
  },
  "data7": "test7"
}
```

my index.php :

```
<?php

/* DEBUG FUNCTION */
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'test_controller.php';
$controller = new Controller();
$controller->dispatch();
```

my test_controller.php :

```
<?php
require 'test_view.php';
require 'test_model.php';
class Controller
{
protected $view;
protected $model;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->view = new TestView();
        $this->model = new TestModel();
    }
    public function dispatch()
    {
        $json = $this->model->getAPI();
        $this->view->displayHome($json);
    }
}
```

my test_model.php :

```
<?php

class TestModel 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
public function getAPI()
{
    $data = file_get_contents('test.json');
    $json = json_decode($data);
    return $json;
}
}
```

my test_view.php :

```
<?php
class TestView
{
    public function __construct()
    {           
    }    
    public function parseJson($datas){

        $value = '&#8709;';
        $data = (isset($datas)) ? $datas : $value ;
        return $data;    
    }    
    public function displayHome($datas) {    
        $page = $this->parseJson($datas->data1);
        $page .= '<br>';
        $page .= $this->parseJson($datas->nodata);
        $page .= '<br>';
        $page .= $this->parseJson($datas->data6->key1);
        $page .= '<br>';
        $page .= $this->parseJson($datas->data6->nokey);
        $page .= '<br>';
        echo $page;
    }
}
```

The result is :

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$nodata in
> /home/meteobel/networkbell.com/mbell/test/test_view.php on line 21
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$nokey in
> /home/meteobel/networkbell.com/mbell/test/test_view.php on line 25
>
> test1
> ∅
> value1
> ∅

So my question is why I have this error result: "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::"

Of course I simplified my problem as much as possible in this example (keeping the MVC architecture), but in my initial script I have many null values in my json for which I still want to display something (here ∅ = `'&#8709;'`) without generating an error. I think it also slows down my page processing as if PHP was thinking in a vacuum

Thanks

---

EDIT :

I resolve the problem with :

```
$page .= isset($datas->nodata) ? $datas->nodata : '&#8709;';
```

For a generic function and no declare all $datas in isset, we can use eventually

```
$page .= $this->parseJson('$datas->nodata');
```

with eval() function

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: `nodata` and `nokey` don't exist in your JSON, so the error is quite self-explanatory.

Comment: This logic is probably wrong in your function `$data = (isset($datas)) ? $datas : $value ;`, too. You need to check whether the property exists before calling the function

Comment: Thanks Chris Haas. isset is not sufficient to test the existence of datas in my json files?

Comment: El_Vanja I know that, it's precisely the role of my parseJson function to test if a value exists in my json

Comment: `isset` is perfectly sufficient, you're just doing it in the wrong order, as Chris already suggested. You're trying to access the property when passing it into the function, where the check is made. You would need to check before you try to access it.

Comment: with property_exists() ?

Comment: I don't understand how check before try to access it. I have try a lot of methods, not show it, but always there is a bug. Sorry. Can you help me with more détails ? Note that the code works if I don't encounter the ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_report (E_ALL); in the index, everything works perfectly. But with a lot of values, it slows down the processing a lot

Comment: $page .= isset($datas->nodata) ? $datas->nodata : '&#8709;'; there is no warning bug, but that supposes to declare individually each value which doesn't suit me only half. Is there no way to test a null value upstream in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the expression you pass to your function is evaluated *before* the function is called, and the function just sees the *value*, so by the time you check with isset() the warning was already been raised.

The simplest solution is to not use a function at all, and use the ["null coalescing operator"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to keep the code short:

```
$page .= $datas->nodata ?? '&#8709;'
```

You could also put the substitution in a constant or function call to avoid pasting it each time:

```
const NA='&#8709;';
$page .= $datas->nodata ?? NA;
```